# Unarchive a file with a set of provided password list

Tags: macos, archive

Is there a possibility like in jDownloader, where password protected files are automatically extracted by trying all passwords one by one which are provided by the user?

Something like this:

```
$ unarchive foo.rar --password-list baz.txt
```

Comment: Which specific unarchiver are you using?

Comment: @patrix Thanks for your comment! There is no specific unarchiver I use, because the ones I use don't provide this functionality, thus I'm searching for one, which can already do that, if there is any.

Comment: You should provide your edited solution as an answer, not by editing the question.

Comment: @grgarside Alright, I added it as an answer. I don't have to check it as solution do I?

Comment: @Byte No, it's fine to leave the other answer as accepted. Putting your answer as an answer makes it easier to see the development of the solution and is less confusing to search/SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from @patrix works perfect, except for the case, when the password is not available in the provided list, then the archive will produce a lot of 0 byte files. My changed solution checks, if a password matches, then it's continues to unarchive.

```
while IFS= read pwd; do
    if lsar -t "$1" -p "$pwd" | grep "[1-9][0-9]* passed" -E -q; then
        unar -p "$pwd" "$1"
        break
    fi
done < password-list.txt
```

Comment: Ah, great. I didn't have any password-protected archives to test it with.

Answer (score 5):

- Get `unar` from http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline
- Extract the archive and put `unar` (and `lsar`) somewhere your shell can find it.
- Run

  ```
  while IFS= read pwd; do
      unar -p "$pwd" ARCHIVE
  done < password-list.txt
  ```